# AWS RHEL 5 AMI contain a "cloud-user" default user?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rhel5, amazon-ami

Can anyone confirm that Red Hat's AMI for RHEL 5 contains or once contained a user in /etc/sudoers called "cloud-user" (in addition to ec2-user)?  I inherited an environment where our EC2 instances have this and I'm being told it came from the original Red Hat AMI used to build these instances.

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL 5.11 `cloud-user` is not present in `/etc/sudoers` nor `/etc/passwd`

You could spend a few cents and launch a clean RHEL5 instance from an AMI and check this yourself.

The default user for these old RHEL versions was `root`. From RHEL 6.4 onward this changed to `ec2-user`.